# Run Test Cafe using Chrome incognito mode

Tags: testcafe, incognito-mode

I am trying to get a test café script to execute using chrome incognito mode. Can this be done? I cannot seem to find any documentation on it. I feel like this should be a flag in the config file if not a command line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The [incognito](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#incognito) argument causes the browser to launch directly in incognito mode.

To conduct tests in incognito mode of google-chrome, you need to pass arguments for the specified browser and write them right after the browser alias. Enclose the browser call and its arguments with quotes as follows:

---

Using the CLI:

- Use single quotes in *NIX shell or Microsoft PowerShell - `testcafe 'chrome --incognito' test.js`
- Use double quotes in cmd.exe - `testcafe "chrome --incognito" test.js`

---

Using the Test Runner API:

```
await runner
.browsers('chrome --incognito')
.src('./tests/')
.run();
```